# Order by multiple columns with

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-order-by, coalesce

I'm trying to sort a table by multiple columns, but I should shift the most important column.

Given a sample like:

```
Name   Col1 Col2 Col3
Paul      1    2    1
John      1    1    1
Greg   NULL    2    1
Jane      2    2    1
```

I would like the data to be sorted like `John`, `Paul`, `Greg` and `Jane`.

If I do `ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3`, `Greg` is the first result because of `NULL`.
What I'm trying to do is to "shift" the columns, to discard all the NULL values

Edited:

The desired result is

- John
- Paul
- Greg
- Jane

Greg ends up third because the query should remove the null value, working on a "fixed" version like

```
Name   Col1 Col2 Col3
Paul      1    2    1
John      1    1    1
Greg      2    1    -  <== Greg cols moved to the left by one step
Jane      2    2    1
```

Edit2:

I think that something like the [COALESCE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-coalesce/) function should help.
If I run:

```
SELECT Name, COALESCE(Col1, Col2, Col3, 0) FROM Table1
```

The result is:

```
Paul  1
John  1
Greg  2
Jane  2
```

Comment: Maybe sort in reverse order?

Comment: Please add your desired result to support the question.

Comment: Is there a case that all 3 columns are null? If yes, would that row be first in the results?

Comment: @forbas , no there is no such case, at least one column (Col3) is always filled

Comment: It seems like the model is incorrect to start with. If the values in columns `Col1`, `Col2` and `Col3` are of the same "type", such that it makes sense to compare those values with each other, sort by them, etc, it strongly indicates that they should have been stored in *one* column. Perhaps in a child table with another column containing and *naming* the significance of the `1`, `2` and `3` pieces of data that have been inappropriately pushed into metadata instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  I think you are right, sadly I'm in no such power of modifying the table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CASE` expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause to check whether a column is null and needs to be shifted:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY COALESCE(Col1, Col2, Col3),
         CASE 
           WHEN Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(Col2, Col3) 
           WHEN Col2 IS NOT NULL THEN Col3 
         END,
         CASE WHEN Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col2 IS NOT NULL THEN Col3 END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d2cf4811c4a70b16c9839d9130d6f6f2).

Answer (score 1):

You Need to derive a new column as per the required order using case statement and use that column to sort the result like below.

```
select Name,col1,col2,col3
from(
Select *,case when Name='John' then 1
              when Name='paul' then 2
              when Name= 'Greg' then 3
              when Name = 'Jane' then 4
              else 5
        end as sortid
from test
) a
order by sortid, Name
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think I'm having a problem explaining my self, column Name does not matter for the sorting, only Col1, Col2 and Col3